# Can't create python virtualenv FileNotFoundError wheels.lock

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am working in a system for which virtualenv is not installed system wide. I do not have root access to install it system wide.

After installing virtualenv for me as user with `pip3 install --user virtualenv`, creating a virtual environment with
`python3 -m virtualenv testenv` fails with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/python/share/virtualenv/seed-v1/3.6/wheels.lock'
```

The folder  `/path/to/python/share/virtualenv/` does not exist.

How can I use virtualenv even so it is not installed system wide?

Comment: Just linking Jeff Atwood's post about why asking and answering your own questions in a good thing: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem seems to be that virtualenv tries to write to the seed-v1 folder for which I don't have permissions.

After setting the [recently introduced](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/20.0.4/changelog.html#features-20-0-2) `VIRTUALENV_OVERRIDE_APP_DATA` to a folder with write permission I can use virtualenv  like expected.